# Rails: From UUID to ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

I've created a model `Order` with UUID as the primary key.
Now, I'd like to change it back to a normal incremental integer.

I've tried to run a migration like:

```
add_column :orders, :id, :primary_key
```

But it obviously doesn't work because there is already an `id` column.

I've found many posts on how to go from id to uuid, but not how to reverse it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does the table have data?

If no, just drop old id column and add new:

```
remove_column :orders, :id
add_column :orders, :id, :primary_key
```

If yes, rename `id` column to `id_deprecated`

```
rename_column :orders, :id, :id_deprecated
add_column :orders, :id, :primary_key
```

and add your logic to handle references of old_id in other tables.

Comment: If there's other associations this could be far from trivial to do. You need a mapping table from UUID -> ID and then need to update *everything*.

Comment: no need to have another table for map, `id_deprecated` <-> `id` would be available in `orders` and then it's just a matter of `join` and updating other tables

Comment: Not if you've dropped the original UUID value in the primary table. How will you match up the other records?

Comment: The answer specifically mentions to `rename` and not `remove` in that situation

Answer (score 2):

Heres a migration to automatically convert all UUID's to Integer ID's within a Rails app.

For further optimized code see: [github.com/westonganger/rails_uuid_to_integer_primary_keys](https://github.com/westonganger/rails_uuid_to_integer_primary_keys)

```
class ChangeUuidToInteger < ActiveRecord::Migration::Current
  def change
    ### LOAD ALL MODELS for `.subclasses` method
    Dir.glob(Rails.root.join("app/models/*.rb")).each{|f| require(f) }

    id_map = {}

    ApplicationRecord.subclasses.each do |outer_klass|
      outer_klass.reset_column_information

      if outer_klass.column_for_attribute(outer_klass.primary_key).type == :uuid
        case outer_klass.connection.adapter_name
        when "Mysql2"
          execute "ALTER TABLE #{outer_klass.table_name} DROP PRIMARY KEY;"
        else
          result = outer_klass.connection.execute("
            SELECT ('ALTER TABLE ' || table_schema || '.' || table_name || ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' || constraint_name) as my_query
            FROM information_schema.table_constraints
            WHERE table_name = '#{outer_klass.table_name}' AND constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY';")
              
          sql_drop_constraint_command = result.values[0].first

          execute(sql_drop_constraint_command)
        end

        rename_column outer_klass.table_name, outer_klass.primary_key, "tmp_old_#{outer_klass.primary_key}"

        add_column outer_klass.table_name, outer_klass.primary_key, outer_klass.connection.native_database_types[:primary_key]

        outer_klass.reset_column_information

        records = outer_klass.all

        if outer_klass.column_names.include?("created_at")
          records = records.reorder(created_at: :asc)
        end

        id_map[outer_klass] = {}

        records.each_with_index do |record, i|
          old_id = record.send("tmp_old_#{outer_klass.primary_key}")

          if record.send(outer_klass.primary_key).nil?
            new_id = i+1
            record.update_columns(outer_klass.primary_key => new_id)
          else
            new_id = record.send(outer_klass.primary_key)
          end

          id_map[outer_klass][old_id] = new_id
        end

        remove_column outer_klass.table_name, "tmp_old_#{outer_klass.primary_key}"

        outer_klass.reset_column_information
      end
    end

    ApplicationRecord.subclasses.each do |inner_klass|
      inner_klass.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).each do |reflection|
        if inner_klass.column_for_attribute(reflection.foreign_key).type == :uuid
          if reflection.polymorphic?
            ### POLYMORPHIC BELONGS TO
            
            #null_constraint = inner_klass.columns.find{|x| x.name == reflection.foreign_key }.null
            if inner_klass.connection.index_exists?(inner_klass.table_name, reflection.foreign_key)
              remove_index inner_klass.table_name, reflection.foreign_key
            end
            rename_column inner_klass.table_name, reflection.foreign_key, "tmp_old_#{reflection.foreign_key}"
            add_column inner_klass.table_name, reflection.foreign_key, :bigint#, null: null_constraint
            add_index inner_klass.table_name, reflection.foreign_key

            inner_klass.reset_column_information
            
            id_map.each do |outer_klass, inner_id_map|
              records = inner_klass
                .where("#{inner_klass.table_name}.tmp_old_#{reflection.foreign_key} IS NOT NULL")
                .where("#{reflection.foreign_type}" => outer_klass.name)

              records.each do |record|
                old_id = record.send("tmp_old_#{reflection.foreign_key}")

                if old_id
                  new_id = inner_id_map[old_id]

                  if new_id
                    ### First Update Column ID Value
                    record.update_columns(reflection.foreign_key => new_id)
                  else
                    # Orphan record, we just clear the value
                    record.update_columns(reflection.foreign_key => nil)
                  end
                end
              end
            end

            ### Then Change Column Type
            remove_column inner_klass.table_name, "tmp_old_#{reflection.foreign_key}"

            inner_klass.reset_column_information

          elsif id_map[reflection.klass]
            ### DIRECT BELONGS TO
            
            inner_id_map = id_map[reflection.klass]

            #null_constraint = inner_klass.columns.find{|x| x.name == reflection.foreign_key }.null
            if inner_klass.connection.index_exists?(inner_klass.table_name, reflection.foreign_key)
              remove_index inner_klass.table_name, reflection.foreign_key
            end
            rename_column inner_klass.table_name, reflection.foreign_key, "tmp_old_#{reflection.foreign_key}"
            add_column inner_klass.table_name, reflection.foreign_key, :bigint#, null: null_constraint
            add_index inner_klass.table_name, reflection.foreign_key

            inner_klass.reset_column_information

            records = inner_klass.where("#{inner_klass.table_name}.tmp_old_#{reflection.foreign_key} IS NOT NULL")

            records.each do |record|
              old_id = record.send("tmp_old_#{reflection.foreign_key}")

              if old_id
                new_id = inner_id_map[old_id]

                if new_id
                  ### First Update Column ID Value
                  record.update_columns(reflection.foreign_key => new_id)
                else
                  # Orphan record, we just clear the value
                  record.update_columns(reflection.foreign_key => nil)
                end
              end
            end

            ### Then Change Column Type
            remove_column inner_klass.table_name, "tmp_old_#{reflection.foreign_key}"

            inner_klass.reset_column_information
          end
        end
      end

      inner_klass.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_and_belongs_to_many).each do |reflection|
        if id_map[reflection.klass]
          inner_id_map = id_map[reflection.klass]

          #null_constraint = join_klass.columns.find{|x| x.name == reflection.foreign_key }.null
          if inner_klass.connection.index_exists?(reflection.join_table, reflection.association_foreign_key)
            remove_index reflect.join_table, reflection.association_foreign_key
          end
          rename_column reflect.join_table, reflection.association_foreign_key, "tmp_old_#{reflection.association_foreign_key}"
          add_column reflect.join_table, reflection.association_foreign_key, :bigint
          add_index reflect.join_table, reflection.association_foreign_key

          inner_id_map.each do |old_id, new_id|
            if new_id
              ### First Update Column ID Value
              execute "UPDATE #{reflection.join_table} SET #{reflection.association_foreign_key} = '#{new_id}' WHERE tmp_old_#{reflection.association_foreign_key} = '#{old_id}'"
            end
          end

          execute "DELETE FROM #{reflection.join_table} WHERE tmp_old_#{reflection.association_foreign_key} NOT IN ('#{inner_id_map.values.join("','")}')"

          remove_column reflection.join_table, "tmp_old_#{reflection.association_foreign_key}"

          #join_klass.reset_column_information
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```